# Jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: e.ui.isOverAxis is not a function

Tags: javascript

Here is my code while doing reordering of my table where my:

```
<tbody id="sortableBookmarks">

$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sortableBookmarks").sortable({
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
            dropOnEmpty:false, 
            stop : function(event,ui){
                $.post("<?php echo HTTP_ROOT.'users/reorder_bookmark'?>", function(res){},'json');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: even the ajax call is not going. Only this error is coming inside the console.

Comment: Please take a look on how to ask a good question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It looks like you might have a corrupt or incomplete jquery ui bundle. Try using a new clean bundle to see if the problem still appears.

Comment: @Deadron is there any way to solve the issue??

Comment: Replace your jquery ui library url with https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js and see if the issue still occurs.  If it does you know your issue is your jquery ui bundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pewn0.png)Simply go to console and there will be a jquery file at the right.
Search that file inside your project folder.
There could be some restrictions.
So just simply add your page name(on which page you are working on) within that condition.